# Django - Wants to restrict access to all of them to only logged-in users and I already have 100's of functions, is their anyway to add it directly?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-views, django-templates

In Python-Django views.py file I have 100's of functions and I want to restrict access to all of them to only logged-in users. I'm aware that I can add "@login_required(login_url='/admin/login/')" above every function and I works well.

But as there are lots of function then adding it can be quite cumbersome. So, is there any way to achieve this without manually adding it to each and every function.

Helps are highly appreciated.

```
@login_required(login_url='/member/login/')
def dashboard(request):
    id = request.user.id
    result = User.objects.get(pk=id)
    context={'result' : result}
    return render(request, 'member/dashboard.html', context)
```

I want to restrict access to all of them to only logged-in users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to work with some middleware to do this:

```
# app_name/middleware.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


class LoginRequiredMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        self.restricted_get_response = login_required(
            get_response
        )

    def __call__(self, request):
        if request.path == settings.LOGIN_URL:
            return self.get_response(request)
        return self.restricted_get_response(request)
```

We don't want to restrict the `/member/login/` path, since then one could not log in anyway.

You need to add the middleware *below* the `AuthenticationMiddleware`:

```
# settings.py

# …

LOGIN_URL = '/member/login/'

# …

MIDDLEWARE = [
    # …,
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    # …,
    'app_name.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware',
    # …
]
```

Comment: There's a package https://github.com/mgrouchy/django-stronghold for this, which implements settings-configured exceptions so you can have some public URLS. It seems to be unmaintained, but it works and the source isn't large.